# java: NoClassDefFoundError when running from terminal but not from netbeans

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, terminal

I'm seeing weird behavior when I try to run my jar file. I can run and execute my java app from netbeans without any problem. But when I tried to run the jar file from terminal I'm getting a `NoClassDefFoundError` exception in some java classes.

stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.nio.file.TempFileHelper
at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:805)
at sun.font.FcFontConfiguration.writeFcInfo(FcFontConfiguration.java:391)
at sun.font.FcFontConfiguration.init(FcFontConfiguration.java:100)
at sun.font.FcFontConfiguration.<init>(FcFontConfiguration.java:75)
at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:747)
at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorIm
```

Passing he verbose argument to java, I can see `java.nio.file.TempFileHelper` loaded.

im running my app in linux (Fedora 20)

Excerpt: `[Loaded java.nio.file.TempFileHelper from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.79-2.5.5.0.fc20.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar]`

verbose log: http://pastebin.com/ekuQfkgG

What can I do?

EDIT:
running my app using the same java interpeter used to compiled the app works:

```
 /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/bin/java -jar InstaladoruraClientes/Cliente.jar
```

Comment: What Java version are you using in NetBeans and the terminal?  Can you paste the full `javac` call you are making?

Comment: I'm building my app using netbeans, and netbeans is using jdk7

Comment: You should check your manifest file in the generated jar. It contains the classpath used to execute with `-jar` option. What does the classpath look like seen from the app (`java.class.path` system property or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

you might have forgot to JAVA_HOME as your enviroment variable with the path of the ../bin path

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to install the oracle jdk following [this guide](http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/).

To make easy for every new version, after untar, create a soft link like:

```
ln -s jdk1.8.0_45 jdk
```

and replace in each occurrence in the guide the "jdk1.8.0_45" with "jdk". With this way, every time you need to update to a new version you need only to download it and update the link to jdk.

//ofcourse replace jdk18.0_45 from the example above with that version you have